# Получение личных сертификатов другого пользователя

Tags: c#, windows, безопасность, сертификат

На ОС windows есть некоторая служба, работающая фоном, которая подписывает поступающие к ней из БД файлы.

Есть сертификат, помещенный в хранилище "Личные" определенного пользователя.

Сейчас для того чтобы получить доступ к сертификату для подписи файла службу приходится запускать от имени этого пользователя.

Есть ли возможность запускать службу стандартно, под системной учеткой, но дать ей возможность брать сертификат этого другого конкретного пользователя (грубо - дать ей его логин и пароль), чтобы подписывать файлы?

UPD
Хотелось бы что-нибудь вроде

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(_USERNAME_, _PASS_, StoreName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
X509Certificate2Collection found = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
            serialNumberString,
            false);
```

Comment: хранилище на то и личное. засовывайте сертификат в хранилище системной учетки от которой работает сервис или в хранилище машины.

Comment: Да, это можно сделать. Набираете в гугле "_Windows impersonation_" и изучаете. Начать можно с [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/impersonation).

Comment: @freim спасибо, вполне подойдет. оформляйте как ответ

Comment: Не, на ответ это все-таки не тянет, так, направление поиска. Может кто еще ответит по-нормальному, с примером кода. У меня, к сожалению, ничего не нашлось.

Comment: @Monk боюсь, если в локальное хранилище запихать сертификат для подписи, его же может кто угодно использовать? хотелось бы ограничить доступ к сертификату только из этой службы. все-таки ЭЦП для подписи и т.д.

Comment: Это дотнет, все что вы можете сделать, сможет сделать и злоумышленник с тем же доступом. Поэтому сервис подписывающий за людей документы - всегда нехилый шанс на то, что подпишут что-то лишнее. Хороших идей так сразу нет, надо разбираться. ПС: облачные сервисы для подписания используют СМС коды, но имхо - такой себе вариант "безопасности".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце концов остановились на решении установки сертификата в хранилище машины

Через "Выполнить" запускем консоль

mmc.exe

Через меню

Файл - Добавить или удалить оснастку (Ctrl+M)

добавляем оснастку "Сертификаты". Правами должно быть разрешено управление локальной машиной (вроде бы можно подключиться к другому компьютеру, но я этого никогда не делал).

Таким образом получаем доступ к управлению сертификатами на этой машине. А дальше импортируем в требуемое хранилище (например, "Личные") - всё, сертификат установлен и наше ПО может обращаться к нему:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(_USERNAME_, _PASS_, StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
X509Certificate2Collection found = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
        serialNumberString,
        false);
```